# Pinescript array.get() function is not accessing data from my array?

Tags: pine-script

I'm attempting to populate an array with elements when a situation is true. When I use array.push() outside of an IF statement and later use array.get(), I have no errors. However, when I use array.push() inside the IF statement, I get an error that the array is empty. When I print a label to the screen to include array elements and array size, it shows the data and tells me the size. Why won't the array.get() function see the same data? I'd like to use the elements later for comparative analysis but can not retrieve them.

```
myEma = ema(close,14)
var myArray = array.new_float(0)

if close > myEma
    array.push(myArray,close)

lb1 = label.new(bar_index, high, text=tostring(myArray) + " Array size: " + tostring(array.size(myArray),textcolor=color.black),label.delete(lb1[1])

plot(array.get(myArray,0))
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's caused due to the fact that on the first bars of the chart, there are not yet any elements in the array, but you are still trying to `plot` element from the array.

You can check the size of the array before using `plot`:

```
plot(array.size(myArray) > 0 ? array.get(myArray,0) : na)
```

Comment: I suppose I need to better understand how arrays actually work in Pine. Your solution worked perfectly. My end goal is to be able to compare any element against another. Say for example, compare the myArray element index 3 to myArray element index 7. I'm trying to say ```if array.get(myArray,2) > array.get(myArray,6)``` followed by my code but I can't seem to make that work.

Comment: You can use the same logic. Basically the issue is when the script is running on the first bars, there still aren't enough elements in the array, so if you want to check elements at a specific index, you'll need to check if the array has elements in those indexes, and you can use the `array.size` to do so. Keep in mind that variables in pine script are of type `series` and you can reference past values using the history referencing [`[]`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Operators.html#history-reference-operator), so you'll might be better of using "regular" variable